# C# CheckBox List Sending only checked boxes to Word Document

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, ms-word, visual-studio-2019

I'm writing an application where the user can log what items are checked out to students, and print that information to a Word document for the student to sign. The WinForm has 6 CheckBoxes that can be chosen. I have some code that almost works, but still isn't quite giving me the formatted bulleted list of only checked items that I want. Here's the code I have so far:

```
// Add list of checked-out items to Document
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph ul = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
ul.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();

if (listItem1CheckBx.Checked)
{
    ul.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
    ul.Range.InsertBefore(listItem1CheckBx.Text + "\n");
}
if (listItem2CheckBx.Checked)
{
    ul.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
    ul.Range.InsertBefore(listItem2CheckBx.Text + "\n");
}
if (listItem3CheckBx.Checked)
{
    ul.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
    ul.Range.InsertBefore(listItem3CheckBx.Text + "\n");
}
if (listItem4CheckBx.Checked)
{
    ul.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
    ul.Range.InsertBefore(listItem4CheckBx.Text + "\n");
}
if (listItem5CheckBx.Checked)
{
    ul.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
    ul.Range.InsertBefore(listItem5CheckBx.Text + "\n");
}
if (otherChckBx.Checked)
{
    ul.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
    ul.Range.InsertAfter(otherListItemTxtBx.Text);
}
```

How can I make this work better and possibly clean up the code at the same time?

Comment: What's the problem? What's the expected behavior?

Comment: @Reza Aghaei I want it to submit a bullet-point list of anywhere from one to 6 items in a Microsoft Word document if the checkboxes are checked, or submit nothing if the checkboxes are empty. Right now, I'm getting either too many bullets with no text with only some of the list items, text on the same line as other list items, or some of the list items without bullet points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
// Add list of checked-out items to Document
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph ul = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);

// Get a list of all items that are checked. This allows us to know how many
// there are for when we add them later.
List<string> checkedItems = GetCheckedItems();

// Only apply the bullet formatting if at least one item is checked. This keeps
// us from adding an empty bullet in the case that nothing is checked.
if (checkedItems.Count > 0)
{
    ul.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
}

for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.Count; i++)
{
    // If this isn't the last item then add a newline.
    if (i != checkedItems.Count - 1)
    {
        ul.Range.InsertBefore(checkedItems[i] + "\n");
    }
    // If this is the last item don't add a newline, otherwise we'll get an 
    // empty bullet at the end.
    else
    {
        ul.Range.InsertBefore(checkedItems[i]);
    }
}
...


private List<string> GetCheckedItems()
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();

    if (listItem1CheckBx.Checked)
    {
        items.Add(listItem1CheckBx.Text);
    }
    if (listItem2CheckBx.Checked)
    {
        items.Add(listItem2CheckBx.Text);
    }
    if (listItem3CheckBx.Checked)
    {
        items.Add(listItem3CheckBx.Text);
    }
    if (listItem4CheckBx.Checked)
    {
        items.Add(listItem4CheckBx.Text);
    }
    if (listItem5CheckBx.Checked)
    {
        items.Add(listItem5CheckBx.Text);
    }
    if (otherChckBx.Checked)
    {
        items.Add(otherListItemTxtBx.Text);
    }

    return items;
}
```

Comment: That definitely makes the list do what it needs to, but it's not showing any bullet points. How do I add those in?

Comment: Never mind! I had added an extra ApplyBulletDefault(); without realizing it. Your code works great! Thanks so much!!